# appDelegate practices

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, appdelegate

I have a json stored in my app documents folder and I need to use it all over my views. I'm loading and adding the json to a NSMutableArray in each view. But now I learned that I can simple load the array to a NSMutableArray inside the AppDelegate once, and get the information directly from the AppDelegate when I need it.

Is it a bad practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would better use a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for your `JSON storage`, than `AppDelegate`.

So you can use it anywhere in your code like:

```
[[Storage sharedInstance] dataArray];
```

and you can add new methods to this class as your project grows

This is an [article](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/) how to implement singletons in Objective-C

Comment: A beautiful tutorial for singletons is provided by John at http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/

Comment: yeah, this is the same link i used in my last line =)